# How to be sure that rendering is complete after AJAX request

Tags: ajax

After an AJAX request to download a fragment of html, xmlhttp.readyState goes to 4 when the download is complete. It looks like readyState == 4 says nothing (and should say nothing, imo) about the browser's progress in rendering the downloaded matter.

So if my JS depends only upon readyState == 4 before starting to use the downloaded html, I stand a good chance of getting 'whatever_var is undefined' when the JS begins to execute. I don't want that.

How can I find out for sure when the browser is all done rendering?

I'm not using jquery or any other framework.

Test case that shows the problem: http://www.sellmycalls.com/cgi-bin/chain and then when the short page appears, press either of the green buttons in the menu box on the left (labeled "all options" and "watchlist"). Repeat a couple of times and the problem appears. If it looks like the page is hung up, close its tab and bring it up in a new tab.

Use Firebug/FF to see the error on the page; I don't claim in runs in any other browser.

The first time you load this page, you might see some intro material. Dismiss the intro box with the "hide intro"/"hide help" uncolored button in that menu box on the left. The error message on the console will be something like "cx_usrname is undefined". (There's also another error that shows up on this page: "unhandled exception ..." That's a different problem that I'm not worried about yet.)

Comment: Could you give us a test case that exhibits the problem? I'm not sure the browser has to render anything before you execute JS on it. An even better question is how you turn the "downloaded HTML" (a text string) into a DOM.

Comment: Yes, that's right: "downloaded HTML" is the only way I know to describe it. What I really mean is "when the DOM knows about the rendered page" but I don't know how to ask the question that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a function that runs after all of your intensive stuff that starts your interaction with the site. IE, hide the "start" button when the app first runs, then enable it with a function call after all your other code has run.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm looking for a way to know when to run "all the other code".